# Page title set from the title callback doesn't change

Tags: 7, routes

I created a simple download module to redirect a user when they click the download button to another page. Now I need to change the the page title every time a new download is triggered.

This is my code.

```
function custom_download_menu() {
  $items['download-code'] = array(
    'title callback' => 'custom_download_page_title',
    'page callback' => 'custom_download_view',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );

  return $items;
}

function custom_download_page_title() {
  if (isset($_POST['title'])) {
    $title = "Downloading " . $_POST['title'] . " Code";
  }
  else {
    $title = "Download Code";
  }

  return $title;
}
```

But most of the time, the title does not change. It seems that it is using the title that is cached before.

I already added the following code so the page will not be cached:

```
drupal_add_http_header("Last-Modified", gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
drupal_add_http_header("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
drupal_add_http_header("Cache-Control", "post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
drupal_add_http_header("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP/1.0
drupal_add_http_header("Expires", "Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
```

Am I missing something?

Update:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="/download-code">
    <input type="hidden" name="title" id="title" value="[node:title]" />
    <input type="hidden" name="download_code" id="download_code" value="[node:field_code_file]" />
    <input type="hidden" name="uri" id="uri" value="[node:url:relative]" />
    <input type="submit" class="downloadButton" value="Download Code">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the `title arguments` key in `hook_menu`

e.g:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu
 */
function custom_download_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['download-code/%'] = array(
    'title callback' => 'custom_download_page_title',
    'title arguments' => array(1), 
    'page callback' => 'custom_download_view',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );

  return $items;
}

/**
 * hook_menu title callback
 */
function custom_download_page_title($file) {
  if (isset($file) {
    $title = "Downloading " . $file . " Code";
  }
  else {
    $title = "Download Code";
  }
  return $title;
}
```

If the download link is

> download-code/my-file.txt

The page title should then reflect that.

Comment: I'm using $_POST method and not $_GET. So this code still does not work for me.

Comment: You're using HTTP POST to download a file? you should probably use GET

Comment: I can't use HTTP GET because I am using the code above. Please see my update on my post. If I will use GET the file will reveal. I use this because I don't know how to get the file using NID.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a title callback, in the page callback for the download-code page, put the check and set title using, drupal_set_title.

Put this code at the top of the callback function:

```
if (isset($_POST['title']))
        $title = "Downloading " . $_POST['title'] . " Code";
    else
        $title = "Download Code";
drupal_set_title($title);
```

Please make sure you clear menu cache and check to see if this works

Comment: No. There is a value in the POST method. Please try to look at my site at http://bit.ly/1fPIyst. Click the download button at the bottom of the page and look at the Title of the page.

Comment: just had a look, when directly accessing "download-code" page the title is "Download Code" and when reaching through Download button the title is "Downloading Calculator - My First Basic4Android Application Code". This is what you require no?..Are you getting some different behaviour?

Comment: When you reach the /download-code you will see a "Downloading Calculator - My First Basic4Android Application Code" below the "home" menu. But what I mean is the Title of the page. Look at the title bar of your browser and you will see that the title is "Downloading TTJ- Inventory System Code | Free source code, tutorials and articles"

Comment: To make sure that you understand what I main, access the page source of download-code and look at the title tag within the head tag. The value is: <title>Downloading TTJ- Inventory System Code | Free source code, tutorials and articles</title>.

Comment: I saw this. ok let us try this approach. I updated my answer.

Comment: I already updated the code and flush all cache, but the same problem. This time the title tag has this value "<title>Downloading Dennis Class Example Code | Free source code, tutorials and articles</title>". Is this not because of caching? I'm using memcached.

Comment: I also tried to disable and enable the module to no luck.

Comment: memcache - this might be it. For sure the above code works in clean install and I misinterpreted "cache" in your question to drupal cache. Will let you know if I find anything.